# Continous animation after clicking the next button using Easyslider 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, easyslider

Does anybody who has ever used this know how to get the slides to continue scrolling after clicking the next button? Currently if you click on 'next' button, they stay on that slide.

My jQuery skills are slightly below average and I can't figure out myself if there is an easy way of doing it. Any help would be grand :)

Easyslider is a jQuery plugin, Here is the JS:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.easySlider = function(options){

    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = {            
        prevId:         'prevBtn',
        prevText:       'Previous',
        nextId:         'nextBtn',  
        nextText:       'Next',
        controlsShow:   true,
        controlsBefore: '',
        controlsAfter:  '', 
        controlsFade:   true,
        firstId:        'firstBtn',
        firstText:      'First',
        firstShow:      false,
        lastId:         'lastBtn',  
        lastText:       'Last',
        lastShow:       false,              
        vertical:       false,
        speed:          800,
        auto:           true,
        pause:          3000,
        continuous:     true, 
        numeric:        false,
        numericId:      'controls'
    }; 

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

    this.each(function() {  
        var obj = $(this);              
        var s = $("li", obj).length;
        var w = $("li", obj).width(); 
        //var h = $("li", obj).height(); 
        var clickable = true;
        obj.width(w); 
        //obj.height(h); 
        obj.css("overflow","hidden");
        var ts = s-1;
        var t = 0;
        $("ul", obj).css('width',s*w);          

        if(options.continuous){
            $("ul", obj).prepend($("ul li:last-child", obj).clone().css("margin-left","-"+ w +"px"));
            $("ul", obj).append($("ul li:nth-child(2)", obj).clone());
            $("ul", obj).css('width',(s+1)*w);
        };              

        if(!options.vertical) $("li", obj).css('float','left');

        if(options.controlsShow){
            var html = options.controlsBefore;              
            if(options.numeric){
                html += '<ol id="'+ options.numericId +'"></ol>';
            } else {
                if(options.firstShow) html += '<span id="'+ options.firstId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.firstText +'</a></span>';
                html += ' <span id="'+ options.prevId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.prevText +'</a></span>';
                html += ' <span id="'+ options.nextId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.nextText +'</a></span>';
                if(options.lastShow) html += ' <span id="'+ options.lastId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.lastText +'</a></span>';              
            };

            html += options.controlsAfter;                      
            $(obj).after(html);                                     
        };

        if(options.numeric){                                    
            for(var i=0;i<s;i++){                       
                $(document.createElement("li"))
                    .attr('id',options.numericId + (i+1))
                    .html('<a rel='+ i +' href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ (i+1) +'</a>')
                    .appendTo($("#"+ options.numericId))
                    .click(function(){                          
                        animate($("a",$(this)).attr('rel'),true);
                    });                                                 
            };                          
        } else {
            $("a","#"+options.nextId).click(function(){     
                animate("next",true);
            });
            $("a","#"+options.prevId).click(function(){     
                animate("prev",true);               
            }); 
            $("a","#"+options.firstId).click(function(){        
                animate("first",true);
            });             
            $("a","#"+options.lastId).click(function(){     
                animate("last",true);               
            });             
        };

        function setCurrent(i){
            i = parseInt(i)+1;
            $("li", "#" + options.numericId).removeClass("current");
            $("li#" + options.numericId + i).addClass("current");
        };

        function adjust(){
            if(t>ts) t=0;       
            if(t<0) t=ts;   
            if(!options.vertical) {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
            } else {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*h*-1));
            }
            clickable = true;
            if(options.numeric) setCurrent(t);
        };

        function animate(dir,clicked){
            if (clickable){
                clickable = false;
                var ot = t;             
                switch(dir){
                    case "next":
                        t = (ot>=ts) ? (options.continuous ? t+1 : ts) : t+1;                       
                        break; 
                    case "prev":
                        t = (t<=0) ? (options.continuous ? t-1 : 0) : t-1;
                        break; 
                    case "first":
                        t = 0;
                        break; 
                    case "last":
                        t = ts;
                        break; 
                    default:
                        t = dir;
                        break; 
                };  
                var diff = Math.abs(ot-t);
                var speed = diff*options.speed;                     
                if(!options.vertical) {
                    p = (t*w*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { marginLeft: p }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                    );              
                } else {
                    p = (t*h*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { marginTop: p }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                    );                  
                };

                if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
                    if(t==ts){
                        $("a","#"+options.nextId).hide();
                        $("a","#"+options.lastId).hide();
                    } else {
                        $("a","#"+options.nextId).show();
                        $("a","#"+options.lastId).show();                   
                    };
                    if(t==0){
                        $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
                        $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();
                    } else {
                        $("a","#"+options.prevId).show();
                        $("a","#"+options.firstId).show();
                    };                  
                };              

                if(clicked) clearTimeout(timeout);
                if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){;
                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                        animate("next",false);
                    },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
                };

            };

        };
        // init
        var timeout;
        if(options.auto){;
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                animate("next",false);
            },options.pause);
        };      

        if(options.numeric) setCurrent(0);

        if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
            $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
            $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();              
        };              

    });

};

})(jQuery);
```

Demo of what I'm working with: http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/01.html

Comment: The plugin code is not as useful as your own code would be.  Unless you are trying to modify this code so as to use this plugin as a codebase for your own new plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it to work by modifying the easyslider1.7.js file.

Line 195 you have

```
if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       animate("next",false);
    },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
};
```

I added an else statement as follows

```
if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        animate("next",false);
    },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
} else {
    if(clicked && options.auto && !options.numeric) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            animate("next",false);
        },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
    };
};
```

Might not be the most elegant solution (I'm not a javascript or jQuery expert) but it seems to work, although only for the left and right arrows, not the controls.

Answer (score 6):

I was coming from a contribution from Cameron and just edit the condition (remove !clicked):

```
if(options.auto && dir=="next" || dir=="prev"){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       animate("next",false);
    },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the solution to auto continuous slide with numeric control:

Go to **line 107** and change:

this:

```js
animate($("a",$(this)).attr('rel'),true);
```

to this:

```js
animate(parseInt($("a",$(this)).attr('rel')),true);
```

Then, add the following in **line 202**:

```js
} else {    
    if(clicked && options.auto && options.numeric) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            animate("next",true);
        },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
    };
};
```

That fixes the problem!

Cheers!

Comment: can you please write down the exact code which needs to be replaced by the one you posted above?

Answer (score 0):

The entire fixed code:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.easySlider = function(options){

    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = {            
        prevId:             'prevBtn',
        prevText:           'Previous',
        nextId:             'nextBtn',  
        nextText:           'Next',
        controlsShow:   true,
        controlsBefore: '',
        controlsAfter:  '', 
        controlsFade:       true,
        firstId:                'firstBtn',
        firstText:          'First',
        firstShow:          false,
        lastId:                 'lastBtn',  
        lastText:           'Last',
        lastShow:           false,              
        vertical:           false,
        speed:              800,
        auto:               false,
        pause:              2000,
        continuous:     false, 
        numeric:            false,
        numericId:      'controls'
    }; 

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

    this.each(function() {  
        var obj = $(this);              
        var s = $("li", obj).length;
        var w = $("li", obj).width(); 
        var h = $("li", obj).height(); 
        var clickable = true;
        obj.width(w); 
        obj.height(h); 
        obj.css("overflow","hidden");
        var ts = s-1;
        var t = 0;
        $("ul", obj).css('width',s*w);          


        if(!options.vertical) $("li", obj).css({'float':'left','width':w});

        if(options.continuous){
            $("ul", obj).prepend($("ul li:last-child", obj).clone().css("margin-left","-"+ w +"px"));
            $("ul", obj).append($("ul li:nth-child(2)", obj).clone());
            $("ul", obj).css('width',(s+1)*w);
        };  


        if(options.controlsShow){
            var html = options.controlsBefore;              
            if(options.numeric){
                html += '<ol id="'+ options.numericId +'"></ol>';
            } else {
                if(options.firstShow) html += '<span id="'+ options.firstId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.firstText +'</a></span>';
                html += ' <span id="'+ options.prevId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.prevText +'</a></span>';
                html += ' <span id="'+ options.nextId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.nextText +'</a></span>';
                if(options.lastShow) html += ' <span id="'+ options.lastId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.lastText +'</a></span>';              
            };

            html += options.controlsAfter;                      
            $(obj).after(html);                                     
        };

        if(options.numeric){                                    
            for(var i=0;i<s;i++){                       
                $(document.createElement("li"))
                    .attr('id',options.numericId + (i+1))
                    .html('<a rel='+ i +' href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ (i+1) +'</a>')
                    .appendTo($("#"+ options.numericId))
                    .click(function(){                          
                        animate(parseInt($("a",$(this)).attr('rel')),true);
                    });                                                 
            };                          
        } else {
            $("a","#"+options.nextId).click(function(){     
                animate("next",true);
            });
            $("a","#"+options.prevId).click(function(){     
                animate("prev",true);               
            }); 
            $("a","#"+options.firstId).click(function(){        
                animate("first",true);
            });             
            $("a","#"+options.lastId).click(function(){     
                animate("last",true);               
            });             
        };

        function setCurrent(i){
            i = parseInt(i)+1;
            $("li", "#" + options.numericId).removeClass("current");
            $("li#" + options.numericId + i).addClass("current");
        };

        function adjust(){
            if(t>ts) t=0;       
            if(t<0) t=ts;   
            if(!options.vertical) {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
            } else {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*h*-1));
            }
            clickable = true;
            if(options.numeric) setCurrent(t);
        };

        function animate(dir,clicked){
            if (clickable){
                clickable = false;
                var ot = t;             
                switch(dir){
                    case "next":
                        t = (ot>=ts) ? (options.continuous ? (t+1) : ts) : (t+1);                       
                        break; 
                    case "prev":
                        t = (t<=0) ? (options.continuous ? (t-1) : 0) : (t-1);
                        break; 
                    case "first":
                        t = 0;
                        break; 
                    case "last":
                        t = ts;
                        break; 
                    default:
                        t = dir;
                        break; 
                };  
                var diff = Math.abs(ot-t);
                var speed = diff*options.speed;                     
                if(!options.vertical) {
                    p = (t*w*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { marginLeft: p }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                    );              
                } else {
                    p = (t*h*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { marginTop: p }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                    );                  
                };

                if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
                    if(t==ts){
                        $("a","#"+options.nextId).hide();
                        $("a","#"+options.lastId).hide();
                    } else {
                        $("a","#"+options.nextId).show();
                        $("a","#"+options.lastId).show();                   
                    };
                    if(t==0){
                        $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
                        $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();
                    } else {
                        $("a","#"+options.prevId).show();
                        $("a","#"+options.firstId).show();
                    };                  
                };              

                if(clicked) clearTimeout(timeout);
                if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){;
                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                        animate("next",false);
                    },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
                } else {
                    if(clicked && options.auto && !options.numeric) {
                        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                            animate("next",false);
                        },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
                    };

                    if(clicked && options.auto && options.numeric) {
                        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                            animate("next",true);
                        },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
                    };
                };

            };

        };
        // init
        var timeout;
        if(options.auto){;
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                animate("next",false);
            },options.pause);
        };      

        if(options.numeric) setCurrent(0);

        if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
            $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
            $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();              
        };

    });

};
})(jQuery);
```